# Why wasn't this question eligible for code review?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30711374/const-correctness-of-self-made-iterators) question because, IMHO, it would better treated if asked on [codereview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). This question contains indeed working code and its five points ask about const-correctness, maintainability and design.
However, my thoughts turned out to be wrong and my suggestion got declined. What did I miss?

Comment: Questions that have already attracted good answers shouldn't generally be migrated, based on the migration policy.

Comment: @Servy That is true but, when I flagged the question, it had a bunch of views and definitely not the up-votes it eventually received (1 or 2, iirc). What's also doubtful is that the moderator found no evidence in my observations.

Comment: What matters is what's there when the mod goes to handle the flag, not what's there when you flagged it.

Comment: And "found no evidence" is the message for all declined flags.  It really means "no I (we) don't agree."

Comment: @ryanyuyu I received a declined + message; I guess "found no evidence" is default one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your title here reveals your problem.

There is a difference between a post being eligible to be asked on Code Review, and being eligible for migration to Code Review.

As long as the subject matter is on topic for both sites, it is the OP's option where to ask it, and the moderators will respect that choice by declining your flag.  Even if you are 100% correct that the question would have been viable on the other site.

Whenever you flag for migration, you should have a clear explanation why the question would have to be closed if it remains here.